# saving the canvas as a jpg

Tags: java, android

Want to save the current state of my canvas as a picture, jpg file, 
how do u do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- create a new BufferedImage the size of your canvas
- get its graphics object
- call your canvas.paint() to paint into the image
- use ImageIO.save() or whats-it-called to actually save the image

Answer (score 1):

bitmap.compress() is what your looking for.